# complete orthonormal basis in $L^2([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f\in L^2([0,1])$,and if $\{f_n\}$ is orthonormal basis; where $f_n(t)=e^{2\pi int}$, then it is complete; i.e. $\langle f,f_n\rangle =0$ for all $n$ implies $f=0$ and $f\in L^2([0,1])$.

I am not get why this is true. Can anyone help me to understand this?

Comment: your question is too long to be answered and is explained in full detail in many functional or real analysis textbook that cover theory of Hilbert spaces. By example you can read a full explanation [in this free textbook](https://measure.axler.net/)

Comment: @Masacroso Which page?

Comment: @Masacroso I still think it's helpful to put the page number. It means that readers can find the text for themselves and figure out how much of the theory they need refreshed. Just saying "read the whole textbook" is not especially helpful to people seeking out an answer to this question.

Comment: @Theo the main result, that the $f_n$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2$, start in page 355.

Comment: If every $f  \in L^2[0,1]$ can be written as $f= \sum_{n}\langle f,f_n\rangle f_n$, then it is obvious that $f=0$ if $\langle f,f_n\rangle=0$ for all $n$.